# Empty field in native facet script

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a native facet script that checks if a specific field (mapped to type long) in the document is empty, this is how I do it:

`Object fieldValue = doc().get("fieldName");
return  fieldValue == ScriptDocValues.EMPTY;`

However, for some of the documents this returns false even when the field is empty (I've checked this with the exists filter). This behavior is inconsistent and it usually returns the correct result. Furthermore, the same document in a different host with the same mapping, same version and same code - returns the correct result.

Is there a better way to check if a field is empty?

I'm using ElasticSearch 0.90.5 with facet script 1.1.2 and java 1.7u17.

Comment: Probably you have to use something like `doc().containsKey("fieldName")` to check whether the field exists.

Comment: containsKey() would return false only when mapperService.smartNameFieldMapper returns null, in which case get() would have thrown exception, so this can't be it, I'm looking for a more internal way, or even better - an explanation on why I get such inconsistent results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to check for an empty field is:

        `ScriptDocValues value = (ScriptDocValues) doc().get("field2");
        return value.isEmpty();`